# Apple TV triggers TV every 5 minutes

Tags: appletv, hdmi, airplay, screensaver, television

I have set my TV to turn on and/or switch to Apple TV when the ATV wakes up from sleep. Until tvOS 10 it worked as expected but since I upgraded to 11 the other day, the TV switches to the ATV input every (exactly) 5 minutes with a message (translated, but something like this) "Multi purpose remote activated".

First I thought it had something to do with the screen saver since it was set to turn on after five minutes of idling but changing that time out to 10 minutes didn't change anything.

I have restarted the ATV, turned of WiFi on all other devices I have (to make sure they don't use the ATV for AirPlay) and put my ATV remote control in my micro wave oven (since it has a Faraday's cage), all to no avail.

What's going on here?

Update: After leaving the TV off for a day I turned it on and it worked normally for several hours. I then airplayed a youtube video from my phone to the ATV, which made the TV, as expected, automatically switch input source. When done I switched back to regular TV and put the phone in flight mode but five minutes later the ATV triggered again. This continued every five minutes until I pulled the plug on the ATV.

Comment: When I see the words *Multi purpose remote* I think of a Universal Remote. Do you happen to have one? If so, could this explain it in some way? Also, I'm not familiar with the *Multi purpose remote activated* message - is this being triggered by the ATV itself, or by your TV? Finally, one test you haven't tried is actually disconnecting your ATV from power altogether and seeing if your TV still tries switching to the ATV input or not? This would help narrow down the cause somewhat.

Comment: "Do you happen to have one?" - like a remote than can be programmer to control several different units from different brands? No. I have however allowed my TV remote to control the ATV and can use its steering cross and OK button to navigate the ATV.

Comment: Ok, it'd still be good if you could check to see what happens if the ATV is powered off. And maybe repeat your other test, but with both remotes in your microwave. Finally, what about the message itself? Do you have a sense whether it's from the ATV or the TV?

Comment: Will do tonight.

Comment: @Monomeeth Updated the question with more details.